# powershell: Write specific rows from files to formatted csv

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

The following code gives me the correct output to console. But I would need it in a csv file:

```
$array = @{}
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\Logs\*"
foreach($file in $files){
    foreach($row in (Get-Content $file | select -Last 2)){
        if($row -like "Total peak job memory used:*"){
            $sp_memory = $row.Split(" ")[5]
            $array.Add(($file.BaseName),([double]$sp_memory))
            break
        }
    } 
}
$array.GetEnumerator() | sort Value -Descending |Format-Table -AutoSize
```

current output (console):

[image: Output console:]

required output (csv):

[image]

In order to increase performance I would like to avoid the array and write output directly to csv (no append).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line to this -

```
$array.GetEnumerator() | sort Value -Descending | select @{l='FileName'; e={$_.Name}}, @{l='Memory (MB)'; e={$_.Value }} | Export-Csv -path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will give you a `csv` file named `Output.csv` on your desktop.
I am using `Calculated properties` to change the column headers to `FileName` and `Memory (MB)` and piping the output of `$array` to `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

Just to let you know, your variable `$array` is of type `Hashtable` which won't store duplicate keys. If you need to store duplicate key/value pairs, you can use arrays. Just suggesting! :)

Comment: Hashtable is ok - I know, I have choosen a bad name for it :)

Your way is working to output data in a csv but the columns "Filename" and 2Memory (MB)" are concatenated in the same column("A") in Excel

Comment: How exactly are you transmitting your data from `csv` to `excel`?